# IndexedEmbedded not updating other side of relationship?

Tags: nhibernate.search

I have a one to many, let's say company-to-employees. I am trying to use [IndexEmbedded] on Employee's Company reference, so I can perform a employee query similar to: "Company.Name:IBM".  When inserting the employee, this works fine.  However, if I update the Company instance, the lucene index on the employee side does not get updated.  The Lucene index *does* get updated if I update the employee in some other way in the same transaction.

I updated my NHibernate Search based on the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328647/lucene-net-indexes-are-not-updating-when-dealing-with-many-to-many-relationships), but the index still does not get updated.  Here's my relevant configuration:

```
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostUpdate, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostInsert, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostDelete, new FullTextIndexEventListener());
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostCollectionUpdate, new FullTextIndexCollectionEventListener());
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostCollectionRecreate, new FullTextIndexCollectionEventListener());
c.SetListener(ListenerType.PostCollectionRemove, new FullTextIndexCollectionEventListener());
```

Any advice much appreciated.